# Typescript typings for basic recursively curried function

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, typescript-typings, currying

I'm trying to define a basic function with 2 signatures to allow basic currying without including any complicated 3rd party libraries.

This is the basic function, it takes 2 arguments, if the second argument is not provided it returns a function that takes the last argument, then it will execute the function.

```
function concat(x, y) {
  if (arguments.length === 1) {
    return (_y) => concat(x, _y);
  }
  return x.concat(y);
}
```

If I use a separate `index.d.ts` typescript definition file, I can use the following types.

```
export function concat<T>(x: T, y: T): T;
export function concat<T>(x: T): (y: T) => T;
```

However, if I overload the function in a `ts` file I get typedef errors.

```
export function concat<T>(x: T, y: T): T;
export function concat<T>(x: T): (y: T) => T {
  if (arguments.length === 1) {
    return (_y) => concat(x, _y);
  }
  return x.concat(y); // Type error: TS2304: Cannot find name 'y'.
}
```

Is there something I am missing in the type definition inline in the `ts` file?

```js
function concat(x, y) {
  if (arguments.length === 1) {
    return (_y) => concat(x, _y);
  }
  return x.concat(y);
}

// both args provided
console.log(
  concat(['one'], ['two'])
);

// curried
console.log(
  concat(['one'])(['two'])
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mixed the overload declarations with the implementation. They need to be separate, regardless whether they are in the same file or not:

```
export function concat<T>(x: T, y: T): T;
export function concat<T>(x: T): (y: T) => T;
export function concat(x, y?) {
  if (arguments.length === 1) {
    return (_y) => concat(x, _y);
  }
  return x.concat(y);
}
```

Comment: Note: will still get errors about `x.concat` is not a thing, `x` and `y` have no types, blah blah blah, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Bergi, unfortunately, I still get a type error `TS2394: This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.`

Comment: @caTS `concat` was just an example off the top of my head to have dynamic types. I'm really using a maybeOr function. "if the value is null, replace it with the provided `or` value". just didn't want to get bogged down in the implementation so chose something generic.

Comment: Ah, the `y` parameter needs to be optional so that the second overload is accepted. Also requires some liberal sprinkling of `any`s on the implementation - or [really the proper types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVzTtAQxgB4AVAPgAoQAuOMgbQF0AaOAT3qeYEpuWAbgBQoSLESoM2XPnTFy1Ogxb84VLir5wAvBS0ix0eMnRYceAgso0BbTgH47annAA+6jc936evOAEA3sIBmAjqhFAA5kgAtsAoMADOAHQANglRMAAWujo6cACM-sEBAVDAMEhQuFQA+hz+epbyMDTsDbwiAQC+IXAVVTVwIClyRG0cAIRdwj1AA)

Answer (score 1):

Your overload signatures are independent of the function declaration itself. Your function declaration should sport a signature that effectively "combines" the others. Here, that just means `y` has to be optional (since it is required in only one of the two overloads):

```
export function concat<T extends { concat(other: T): T }>(x: T, y: T): T;
export function concat<T extends { concat(other: T): T }>(x: T): (y: T) => T;
export function concat<T extends { concat(other: T): T }>(x: T, y?: T) {
  if (typeof y === "undefined") {
    return (y: T) => concat(x, y);
  }

  return x.concat(y);
}
```

Also, you will probably noticed that I have changed `arguments.length === 1` to `typeof y === "undefined"`. This is just more "modern" and integrates better with TypeScript in a lot of cases (but not this one... sadly). And in the returned function, you have to add a type annotation to the `y` parameter.

I have added a generic constraint as well so when you attempt to call `x.concat` it no longer errors. In case you'll use this for other things that have a concat method, I chose `{ concat(other: T): T }` as the type.

[Here is a playground](https://tsplay.dev/mArnvW), but I am unsure how well this applies to your actual use case...